# Error connecting to SQLite from iPhone

Tags: objective-c, debugging, sqlite, connection

My application shows this error

> `asm CPSqliteConnectionStatementForSQL 0x30897lb3:10`

and it stopped at this breakpoint in debugger

> `0x308971cb  <+0024>  mov    0x8(%edi),%eax`

Does someone know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly code won't tell most of us anything at all, and your question is pretty light on detail about the context in which the problem occurs, such as what your app is trying to do when it crashes, whether this is always reproducible, etc. If you post more information we'll be able to help you more.

If you're debugging in Xcode, trace back up the call stack until you reach your code, then set a breakpoint there and debug your program again. When it stops at that point, try examining the related variables and see if they have the values you expect.

---

**Edit:** At the request of the asker, here is a slight clarification. When it stops at a breakpoint, the Xcode debugger window will look something like this: (from [this section](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/300-Debugging_in_the_Debugger/debugging_in_debugger.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH6-SW15) of Apple's [Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/))

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/art/debugger_disassembly.jpg

The stack frames are shown in the upper-left rectangle, and you can click on a row in the table to jump to that point in the code. Grayed-out lines are those that do not have viewable source code available. Scroll down until you see a line with black text and click on it. This will show you the point at which execution left your code and entered third-party code, and you can then examine variables to get a better idea about what the problem may be. If you have further questions, I highly recommend reading through the debugging guide linked above.

Comment: please explain this in more detailed way

If you're debugging in Xcode, trace back up the call stack until you reach your code, then set a breakpoint there and debug your program again. When it stops at that point, try examining the related variables and see if they have the values you expect.

how do i trace back up the call stack

also tell me if you know how to use instruments and find and remove leaks

Comment: I've edited my answer to describe Xcode debugging in more detail. Using Instruments to examine leaks is an entirely different question. Briefly, you can get going by selecting **Run > Run with Performance Tool > Leaks**. Check out http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/ or search SO or the web for more details.